# Automating commits in a github repository every sunday?

Tags: git, automation, scheduled-tasks, github, task-scheduler

I am using :

1. Google Drive Desktop (as D:/)
2. Github Desktop
3. Windows 10 OS

I have :

1. A directory called "*myNotes*" on my Google Drive ( Which is *D:/myNotes* on Windows Desktop ).
2. I have a private Github repository named "*myNotes*" on my Github.

I did:

1. Made *D:/myNotes* into "*myNotes*" repository.
2. Made some changes, which Github detects & I committed it successfully.

How do I commit & push **automatically** "*myNotes*" repository from Windows 10, every **Sunday**, with **Date** as commit summary?

*note: If I don't turn on the computer on Sunday it should run the next day.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is writing a Windows batch script and scheduling the script to run every Sunday with Windows Task Scheduler. Your would want this batch script to:

1. Stage changes in the local repository
2. Commit changes in your local repository
3. Push to your Github repository

The batch script might look something like:

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set datenow=%%c-%%a-%%b)
cd D:/myNotes
git add --all
git commit -m %%datenow%%
git push
```

Then you would schedule this batch file to execute on a weekly basis through Windows Task Scheduler, as per your desired schedule.

This solution makes a few assumptions:

- You have your git credentials already worked out, e.g. your `git config` for the local myNotes repository already knows where to find your private repo's Github credentials and you've already stored them there, maybe in the Windows Credential Manager.
- git commands are accessible on your command line and you're not using git in a virtual environment, conda environment, or anything like that. If you are, I think activating the virtual environment in the batch script would be required for git commands to execute through the batch script.